# proofs of stochastic boundedness

Tags: st.statistics, notation, pr.probability

I'm looking at some statistical literature and trying to compare the results given there in probabilistic big-Oh notation with statements I'm more familiar with.

In particular, I'm trying to interpret statements of the form
$$
\|\Sigma_{n(p)} - \Sigma \| = O_P\left( \frac{\log p}{n(p)}\right).
$$
As far as i can tell from the rather terse wikipedia page on $o_p$ notation, this means that there is some constant $C$ that is independent of $p$ for which
$$
\lim_{p \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}\left( \|\Sigma_{n(p)} - \Sigma \| > C \frac{\log p}{n(p)}\right) = 0.
$$

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there are no universally agreed upon notations. Maybe [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.3924) will help.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I think I'll also work through a couple of the proofs because I'm interested to see whether they prove their results by getting explicit tail bounds that hold for finite p (and then just state the theorem in a weaker way because of convention) or by using arguments that only hold asymptotically.